# Jquery-How to add class to the child element?

Tags: jquery

I have a html code like this,

```
<div>
    <header>
        <div>Title</div>
        <h5> sub title </h5>
        <button id="submit">Button</button>
    </header>
    <div class="toggleclass"></div>
</div>
```

I want to add a class ("open") to last div tag onclick of button tag.
Onclick i can do like this,

```
$(".toggleclass").addClass("open");
```

But i want it in parent and child structure.Something like,

```
$("#submit").children('div').addClass("open");
```

I tried above code but it is not working

Comment: Question is bit confusing, Submit is the id of a button and you want to access it's child div.

Comment: Yes. Child div with class name "toggleclass"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your HTML:

```
<div>
    <header>
        <div>Title</div>
        <h5> sub title </h5>
        <button id="submit">Button</button>
    </header>
    <div class="toggleclass"></div>
</div>
```

Your jQuery:

```
$("#submit").children('div').addClass("open");
```

Couldn't possibly work, since you've selected the button `#submit` and are then using `children()` to find a child `<div>` of the `<button>` element. You'll note that the `<button>` is not a child of that element. First you have to move to the `<header>` element, and then find the `nextSibling` (albeit using jQuery's `next()` method):

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    // the element that was clicked:
    $(this)
        // finding the first ancestor <header> element:
        .closest('header')
        // finding the next sibling, if it matches the selector:
        .next('.toggleclass')
       // adding the 'open' class-name:
       .addClass('open');
});
```

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    // the element that was clicked:
    $(this)
        // finding the first ancestor <header> element:
        .closest('header')
        // finding the next sibling, if it matches the selector:
        .next('.toggleclass')
       // adding the 'open' class-name:
       .addClass('open');
});
```

```css
.toggleclass::before {
  content: attr(class);
}

.open {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <header>
        <div>Title</div>
        <h5> sub title </h5>
        <button id="submit">Button</button>
    </header>
    <div class="toggleclass"></div>
</div>
```

Or, you could move straight up to the wrapping `<div>`, and from there use `find('.toggleclass')`:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    // the element that was clicked:
    $(this)
        // finding the first ancestor <div> element:
        .closest('div')
        // finding the descendent '.toggleclass' elements:
        .find('.toggleclass')
       // adding the 'open' class-name:
       .addClass('open');
});
```

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    // the element that was clicked:
    $(this)
        // finding the first ancestor <div> element:
        .closest('div')
        // finding the descendent '.toggleclass' elements:
        .find('.toggleclass')
       // adding the 'open' class-name:
       .addClass('open');
});
```

```css
.toggleclass::before {
  content: attr(class);
}

.open {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <header>
        <div>Title</div>
        <h5> sub title </h5>
        <button id="submit">Button</button>
    </header>
    <div class="toggleclass"></div>
</div>
```

If, as the class-name of the `<div>` implies, you want to toggle the `'open'` class-name for the `<div>`, you could use `toggleClass('open')` rather than `addClass('open')`:

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    // the element that was clicked:
    $(this)
        // finding the first ancestor <div> element:
        .closest('div')
        // finding the descendent '.toggleclass' elements:
        .find('.toggleclass')
       // adding the 'open' class-name:
       .toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.toggleclass::before {
  content: attr(class);
}

.open {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <header>
        <div>Title</div>
        <h5> sub title </h5>
        <button id="submit">Button</button>
    </header>
    <div class="toggleclass"></div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#submit').click(function(){     
         jQuery(this).parent('header').next('.toggleclass').addClass('open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$("#submit").parent().parent().find(" > div").addClass("open");
```